# magic mouse vs other mouse for graphic design

Tags: hardware-recommendation, graphics, mouse

I've saw some review that the apple magic mouse isn't recommended by designers.

How do you find the magic mouse in your daily graphic design work? Would you recommend it? If not what are some good alternatives you would recommend? I'm looking for a bluetooth mouse so I wouldn't keep plugging on my usb port. And since I'm using it on my MBP 15, I only have 2 USB ports. So I need to use those ports wisely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only comment for the Magic Trackpad: when I use it all day, every day, my wrist feel pain. It's far from an ideal solution.

I briefly used the Magic Mouse, but for my big hands it was too small.

I used (long enough) a Logitech Bluetooth V470, but every time I went to move the mouse after some seconds of inactivity, the mouse needed some tenths of a second to react. It was driving me crazy (as a side note: I knew of the issue when I ordered the mouse, but I thought: Meh, pussies, it will not be so bad.)

Therefore I would suggests the [Razer Orochi](http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/pd/productID.169419000) (Bluetooth, as you requested). The mouse is incredibly accurate and has the possibility to be used wired as well.

Comment: Great candidate  will be adding this to the list. Thanks Gio. Yeah a bluetooth version is preferable to me since it wouldn't utilize the usb port. I really appreciate review to other alternatives too. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I find the wireless trackpad (Magic Trackpad) to be a much better alternative. Its more responsive and truly supports the multi-touch gestures.

Comment: This is kinda unique solution for me but will try to look at it how it goes. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of the Logitech mice for all things Mac. I feel like the extra buttons and the ergonomics are a lot better for making day-to-day stuff more efficient.

With my work computer, I've got the [Logitech MX 1100 Cordless Laser Mouse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DJ64C0) and love it. I've got a similar one on my home machine.

The Logitech control panel allows you to map all the extra buttons to keystroke combinations, so it's very customizable to your workflow(s).

Comment: I love logitech mice!!! The have great ergonomics. Good when being used for several hours. **All apple mice that I've use so far started to hurt my hands (even arms) after a while.**

Comment: Agreed. Apple makes great products, but IMHO, never have gotten a mouse right, whereas Logitech seems to have it down to a science.

Comment: Is it compatible with macbookpro bluetooth? or you have to stick the usb receiver? Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, that one has its own dongle. A search of Amazon found a few of the Logitechs that are Bluetooth (http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Logitech+bluetooth+mouse&x=0&y=0), including a keyboard/mouse BT combo.

Answer (score 0):

best mouse ever, perfect for long stints in comfort, accurate and simple.
Razer Imperator...yeah yeah i know its a gaming mouse but i promise yo wont look back
no more cramps and wrist pain, low profile with adjustable sensitivity on the mouse so you can make the mouse less sensitive when deep etching.

I highly recommend it